# Mapping scrolling values to change rgba opacity

Tags: jquery, scroll, mapping, viewport, rgba

I would like for the opacity of a color of a div to change as the user scrolls.

It requires a few things though :

- Checking if the div is in **viewport**. Did that with this code :

  ```
  var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),

      ideeHeight = $(this).offset().top;

      if (scrollBottom >= ideeHeight)
  ```
- **Mapping** the values of the scroll to 0.0 -> 1.0 values. This code :

  `var docHeight = $(window).height(),
  opacity = map(ideeHeight, 0, docHeight, 0.0, 1.0);`
- Changing the **opacity** of the div's color as we scroll. I tried this :

  `$(this).css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255," + opacity + ")");`

This does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me where I've made mistakes or if this isn't the right way to do it at all? Thank you!

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  function map(num, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
    return (num - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
  }

  $(".idee").each(function() {
    var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
      ideeHeight = $(this).offset().top;
    if (scrollBottom >= ideeHeight) {
        var docHeight = $(window).height(),
        opacity = map(ideeHeight, 0, docHeight, 0.0, 1.0);

      $(this).css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255," + opacity + ")");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #cdd3d8;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.idee {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 2vw auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/207021/) is a jsfiddle link if it's easier.

Comment: [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) accepts a value "in the range 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive." Also, `opacity` is set to the the output of `console.log()`, which is undefined.

Comment: @showdev oh right, thank you i'll modify that!

Comment: Of course!... Sorry for all those little mistakes, it used to be in a function that's why it had console.log. Thank you! There is still one problem though now, the animation only applies once

Comment: Are you looking to set the opacity based on distance from the current viewport? For example, elements that are scrolled in view have the highest opacity, and opacity for elements drops based on the distance from the viewable area?

Comment: Not exactly, I want the opacity to be at its lowest when the object is entering viewport, and getting higher as it scrolls through the viewport. The opacity should be at 0 when the object is leaving viewport. @showdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want opacity from 0 to 1, the `map()` function should return a *ratio* of an input value mapped to the range of output values, rather than the mapped output value itself.

Based on your comments, I used the `calculateVisibilityForDiv()` function from [Stanislav's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860876/924299) to calculate the ratio of an element that is visible in the viewport. The opacity is then set to the ratio (from 0 to 1) that each element is visible.

```js
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

function calculateVisibilityForDiv($elm) {

  var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  var elmPosition = $elm.offset().top;
  var elmHeight = $elm.height();
  var hiddenBefore = docScroll - elmPosition;
  var hiddenAfter = (elmPosition + elmHeight) - (docScroll + windowHeight);

  if ((docScroll > elmPosition + elmHeight) || (elmPosition > docScroll + windowHeight)) {
    var result = 0;
  } else {
    var result = 1;

    if (hiddenBefore > 0) {
      result -= hiddenBefore / elmHeight;
    }

    if (hiddenAfter > 0) {
      result -= hiddenAfter / elmHeight;
    }

  }
  return result;

}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  $(".idee").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var opacity = calculateVisibilityForDiv($this);
    $this.css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255," + opacity + ")");
  });

}).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
body {
  background: #cdd3d8;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.idee {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 2vw auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Attribution:
Stack Overflow [How much of an element is visible in viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859522/how-much-of-an-element-is-visible-in-viewport);
asked by [tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5214911/tom) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860876/924299) by [Stanislav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1581923/stanislav).

---

Edit:
Modified not to fade out when element leaves viewport.

```js
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

function calculateVisibilityForDiv($elm) {

  var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  var elmPosition = $elm.offset().top;
  var elmHeight = $elm.height();
  var hiddenAfter = (elmPosition + elmHeight) - (docScroll + windowHeight);
  var ratio = 1 - (hiddenAfter / elmHeight);
  return ratio > 0 ? (ratio < 1 ? ratio : 1) : 0;

}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  $(".idee").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var opacity = calculateVisibilityForDiv($this);
    $this.css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255," + opacity + ")");
  });

}).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
body {
  background: #cdd3d8;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.idee {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 2vw auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="idee">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually closer to what I want to do, but not exactly it.. Sorry^^'
What I'd like is for the div to only have its opacity to increase, so it's 0 when it gets in the viewport and 100 when it leaves. I don't know if it's really clear, I can make an image to illustrate if you'd like

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It's great. I'm still having trouble understanding all the variables but I'll get into it. Have a nice day