# Percentage of scroll completeness of a div

Tags: javascript

Similar, but not exactly like [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859522/how-much-of-an-element-is-visible-in-viewport), I want to know the percentage of scroll "lifecycle" of any given `div` inside a scrollable document.

In other words:

1. When the **top** edge of the `div` is aligned with the **bottom** edge of the visible viewport, it's 0%
2. When the **bottom** edge of the `div` is aligned with the **top** edge of the visible viewport, it's 100%
3. If the `div` is below the visible viewport, it always remains 0%
4. If the `div` is above the visible viewport, it always remains 100%

I tried adapting the solution from that other question, as well as a plugin like [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Determine-Element-Visibility-Percentage.html); however in both of these cases the percentage decreases once the div begins scrolling out of view at the top of the viewport, which is not what I want.

I've attempted to do the maths on my own in this JSFiddle, but haven't been very successful: https://jsfiddle.net/5h3tdmb4/

```
var pct = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight <= target.offsetTop) ? 0 : (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) / (target.offsetTop + target.offsetHeight - window.scrollY);
```

How can the above calculation be achieved in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Please share some code with what you have tried so far.

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson This is as far as I've gotten: https://jsfiddle.net/5h3tdmb4/

Comment: You should make the code part of your question rather than on a 3rd service, like jsFiddle, to keep everything in one place :) You can create a code snipped.

Comment: did you try intersection observer as mentioned in the first article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be it [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1x2vh9f/)... i just fixed the maths and changed how the pecentage was getting calculated :

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var itemLength = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) <= target.offsetTop 
  ? 0 
  : ((window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - target.offsetTop) <= (window.innerHeight + target.offsetHeight)
  ? (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight - target.offsetTop)
  : (window.innerHeight + target.offsetHeight)

  var percentage = Math.round((itemLength * 100) / (window.innerHeight + target.offsetHeight))
  /* Show in DOM */
  document.getElementById("pct").innerHTML =  percentage + "%";
});
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!