# How can I find a top element in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get a top element ([Element Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)) from the viewport of a web page with JavaScript. (If any part of the top boundary of an html element is visible on the viewport that element is within the viewport)

[image] [image]

**The approach I came up was:**

1. Find all the elements with `document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")`
2. Check if each element is in the viewport with [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)
3. Get the element with the lowest `el.getBoundingClientRect().top` value from the matching elements of the step 2

If there are many element at the same level (Eg: parents and children), matching any of them would be ok.

This seems to be too much code for a small requirement. Is there a shorter approach?

Comment: Can you use the solution here [How much of an element is visible in viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33859522/2430549) and simply check for first element that is `100%` in viewport?

Comment: Hi I think your answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350581/how-to-get-an-elements-top-position-relative-to-the-browsers-viewport). Please check I hope it is useful